How to expose serial interface to the docker host?
I have a python dockerized service that creates a TTY interface using PSL pty.
import os, pty

server, device = pty.openpty()
tty_name = os.ttyname(device)

I can see this interface created within the container /dev/pts/0:
ls -l /dev/pts
total 0
crw--w---- 1 aqlog tty  136, 0 Apr 28 14:50 0

Now I want to expose it (I guess through volumes) to the host in order to have external service to connect it using serial:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty_host")

I cannot simply map a volume:
volumes:
  - "/dev/tty_host:/dev/pts/0"

Because the file does not exists a image build it is created at container run.
I tried to create it at image build using touch, but it fails due to permission error:
RUN su -c "touch /dev/pts/0"

So my question is: Is it possible to expose to docker host a serial interface created within a container? If so, how should I proceed?

That seems like an unusual way to communicate with a process.  Can you use a TCP socket instead?  That's less finicky in general (it doesn't require device special files) and much better supported in Docker.

@DavidMaze I already have socket doing the same, it works like a charm. Now I want to emulate serial ports using the same docker pattern, but indeed it seems a bit tricky.

openpty just opens stdin here. Just write to docker stdin. Pts is a special character device file. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file , https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt and https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/1565922921/ch03s02.html . Read about mknod.
